# Unable to locate simple switch case enum error

Tags: c++

I'm trying to learn using enum's in switch case statements but keep getting the error "expected unqualified-id".  I can't find anything so far that can point my towards the issue.

thanks for your help!

I am using VSCode on a Mac.  Here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main() {

enum day_code{Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Error};

 switch (day_code){

 case 0:
     cout << "Case 0 is: " << endl;
     break;
 case 1:
     cout << "Case 1 is: " << endl;
     break;
case 2:
     cout << "Case 2 is: " << endl;
     break;
case 3:
     cout << "Case 3 is: " << endl;
     break;
case 4:
     cout << "Case 4 is: " << endl;
     break;
 default:
     break;
 
 }
    
cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Snippy of VSCode/Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpMhN.png)

Comment: You forgot to declare variable of `day_code` type to use it in `switch`.

Comment: `day_code` is a type, not a variable. That is, this has the same form as `switch (int) { case 0: ...`.

Comment: Why are you going to the trouble of defining an enumerated type, and then not using the named values?   You are aware that you can do things like `case Sunday :` instead of `case 0 :`?   In any event, create a variable of type `day_code`, give it a value, and then use the name of that variable in the `switch`, not the type.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I understand what's going on a little better now!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an Enumerator like that you have to create a specific object of that type and then put that into your switch-statement.

Here your code edited, no errors and prints out `Case 0 is:` like intended:

```
enum day_code { Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Error };

day_code test = Sunday;

switch (test) {

case 0:
    cout << "Case 0 is: " << endl;
    break;
case 1:
    cout << "Case 1 is: " << endl;
    break;
case 2:
    cout << "Case 2 is: " << endl;
    break;
case 3:
    cout << "Case 3 is: " << endl;
    break;
case 4:
    cout << "Case 4 is: " << endl;
    break;
default:
    break;

}

cout << endl;
return 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help on this MathewHD.  It's a little clearer now what I need to do.

Comment: Was your question answered,because if it was it would be nice if you mark it as the correct answer. Thanks and no problem.